# Is there a way to know the duration for which the connection is open using lsof?

Tags: mac-osx, connection, lsof

If not possible with lsof what other way to find the time for which the connection is open on a machine.

Please do let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  The kernel doesn't store that kind of info.